# Logging when vscode c++ extension intellisense is scanning workspace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I use the command `make VERBOSE=1` the output shows the compiler scanning through the codebase.
I want to see similar output from the vscode c++ extension when it is scanning through the codebase, like if it cannot locate a file. I tried to produce such logs in the output console of vscode, but haven't been able to output anything useful. What kind of command does vscode run when it is emulating the compiler to scan the codebase? The reason I want these logs is to get more details about why red squiggly lines are being produced.

I've followed these steps to change settings:

To turn on full logging for the language server, follow these steps:

Open the Command Palette and choose Preferences: Workspace settings.

Search for "logging" in the search box.

Find C_Cpp: Logging Level and change the level to Debug.